# Read Bytes from Request Content

Tags: c#, bytestream

```cs
var bytes = Request.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync().Result;
```

hello, is there any other method that read bytes from content? expect this one

Comment: Why you don't want to use this one ?

Comment: What framework are you using? Including more details/information in your question will help people answer it.

Comment: well, i have some problems and think it might be the one but anyway i want to exclude it from problems list :D

Comment: Entitiy Framework

Comment: The chances that any problems with reading bytes from the request are *due to this specific function call* are miniscule. Describe the problems.

Comment: when im reading file and then saving it there are adding some extra content while i open it with notepad, so i want to understand is this ReadAsByteArrayAsync() adds this content or the file which im reading already has this content

Comment: The only problem with the code here is that you are calling `.Result` on a `Task` (which is very dangerous practice) and not `await`ing it, but even that won't "corrupt" the data. If you have an error, then it is somewhere else in your code and this question is meaningless.

Comment: understand, thanks

Comment: `var bytes = await Request.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync();`

Answer (score 0):

You can also stream the contents into a streamreader
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.streamreader?view=net-6.0
This code is from the Microsoft website. You can replace "TestFile.txt" for a stream.

```
            // Create an instance of StreamReader to read from a file.
            // The using statement also closes the StreamReader.
            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("TestFile.txt"))
            {
                string line;
                // Read and display lines from the file until the end of
                // the file is reached.
                while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(line);
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to read content as a string follow code part will help you.

```
public async Task<string> FormatRequest(HttpRequest request)
    {
        //This line allows us to set the reader for the request back at the beginning of its stream.
        request.EnableRewind();

        var body = request.Body;

        //We now need to read the request stream.  First, we create a new byte[] with the same length as the request stream...
        var buffer = new byte[Convert.ToInt32(request.ContentLength)];

        //...Then we copy the entire request stream into the new buffer.
        await request.Body.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

        //We convert the byte[] into a string using UTF8 encoding...
        var bodyAsText = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer);

        //..and finally, assign the read body back to the request body, which is allowed because of EnableRewind()
        request.Body.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        request.Body = body;

        return bodyAsText;
    }
```

Comment: technically, `ReadAsync` is not required to copy more than 1 byte; IMO you should loop here, always checking the return value from `ReadAsync`

Comment: actually  in most cases we set condition for in that code part for 2 kb like this:   return Encoding.Unicode.GetByteCount(bodyAsText) <= 2048 ? bodyAsText : "Body size is large than 2 Kb";

Comment: That changes nothing about ReadAsync